# Complex logarithm function.

Tags: complex-analysis

It is clear that if log(z) is complex logarithm function then $$log(i^{2})\neq 2log(i)$$ and if Log(z) being principal logarithm function then $$Log(i^{3})\neq 3Log(i)$$ I want to find condition under which $$log(z^{n})= n log(z) ~and~  Log(z^{n})= nLog(z) ~(n\in\mathbb{N})$$ Is there some restriction under which above equalities holds? Please help me in this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you denote $\log$ isn't a function as it has multiple values, so the inequality doesn't have a precise meaning.

Comment: yes it is not function bur still we can find values of it...

Comment: i am also write one branch of that function..

Comment: as a set we can talk about that...

Comment: How is it clear that the equality doesn't hold ?

Comment: $log(-1)=\{ \pi+2n\pi\}$ but $2log(i)=2\{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$, where $0\le\theta<2\pi$, so that

$$\log(z)=\log(r)+i\theta+2k\pi.$$
Then
$$\log(z^n)=\log(r^ne^{in\theta})=n\log(r)+in\theta+2k\pi,$$
while
$$n\log(z)=n\log(r)+in\theta+2nk'\pi.$$

The two solution sets coincide only when 
$$\color{green}{n=1}.$$

For convenience, let us define the function $Log$ as having an imaginary part between $0$ (inclusive) and $2\pi$ (exclusive).
We have

$$\text{Log}(z^n)=n\log(r)+i(n\theta\bmod 2\pi),$$
while
$$n\text{ Log}(z)=n\log(r)+in\theta.$$

The imaginary parts are equal when $$n\theta<2\pi,$$ i.e.

$$\color{green}{n\,\Im(\text{Log}(z))<2\pi}.$$
Similar relations can be drawn for other definitions of the principal branch.

Comment: Thanking you for your precise time and good explanation...