# Lesser known forms of Euler's identity

Tags: complex-numbers, transcendental-numbers

https://twitter.com/martinmbauer/status/1763622278128947464?t=YObGhK4ZqjAXrwPaHxB8gw&s=19

> Many know Euler's identity, but did you also know that
>
> $|e^{i\pi}| = |\pi^{ie}| = |i^{\pi e}| = 1$

While the claim about $\pi$'s powers feels intriguing to me (for I don't know any better), the claim about $i$'s powers feels outrageous.

$πe = 8.53973422...$

$i^x; x ∈ ℤ$, is one of $\{ 1, i, -1, -i \}$, and that's "if and if only" as far as I know. 8.539... is not an integer so the last identity must be false. Is the quoted tweet just misinformation or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: All this says it that the norm is equal to 1. So write $i = e^{i \pi/2}$ and so $i^{\pi e} = (e^{i \pi/2})^{\pi e} = e^{i \frac{\pi^2}{2} e}$ which has norm 1.

Comment: @m-stgt $~|-1| \neq -1.$

Comment: I'm not sure how $i^{\pi e}$ is defined or evaluated.

Comment: Moreover, $\pi^{ie} = e^{\ln(\pi) ie} = e^{i \theta}$ where $\theta=e \ln(\pi) \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: More general: $\left| x^{i} \right| = \left| \left( e^{\ln\left( x \right)} \right)^{i} \right| = \left| e^{\ln\left( x \right) \cdot i} \right| = \left| \cos\left( \ln\left( x \right) \right) + \sin\left( \ln\left( x \right) \right) \cdot i \right| = \sqrt{\cos^{2}\left( \ln\left( x \right) \right) + \sin^{2}\left( \ln\left( x \right) \right)} = 1$ for $x > 0$ and only taking the main branch of the $\ln$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some misinformation here or at least omitted information.  The first two terms, $e^{i\pi}$ and $\pi^{ie}$ are well defined by Euler's formula.  Both have a complex value with norm $1$ by rewriting them as:

$$ e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta $$

for a real number $\theta$ (which is $\theta=\pi$ in the first case and as DarkLordofPhysics and Kevin Dietrich point out in comments, $\theta = e \ln \pi$ in the second case).

The third term $i^{\pi e}$ does not have a conventional definition.  Attempts to apply Euler's formula (or similar) result in a multiple valued expression, centering on the multivalued [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) $\ln i$.

The restrictions to make a well-defined function out of the complex logarithm are called [branch cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts), and this topic comes up fairly often in related Questions asked here in the past, such as [Complex logarithm function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484342/complex-logarithm-function).